# How do you plug an unused hole as per the NEC for a liquid tight enclosure?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, hole

I have been looking for a way to seal a liquid tight product using Listed blanking plugs / Cap-offs or similar to comply with the NEC (US National Electrical Code). We wanted to use [Conduit Entry Blind Plug CXP724](http://www.tnb.ca/en/catalogues/online/industrial_mro/pdf/c5/fittings_eng.pdf) but it is not UL listed.

The case is aluminium and the suggested method is to use some thing like a [H125CAP](http://www.tnb.ca/en/catalogues/online/industrial_mro/pdf/c5/fittings_eng.pdf) from Thomas and Betts.

However it is too tall. The threads are to long and this is a problem for the internals of the device.

As this is for the US market I'm way out of my depth (UK/European)
And the difference in names is driving me crazy .... but at least I learnt a thing or two.

As this is the sort of thing an Electrician is likely to meet all the time in building electrical's I thought this might be a good place to ask.

Comment: It sounds like you're **making** a product, not **installing** a product.  So you'll want to be concerned with [Underwriters Laboratories (UL)](http://www.ul.com/global/eng/pages/?noredirect), not [National Electrical Code (NEC)](http://www.nfpa.org/aboutthecodes/AboutTheCodes.asp?DocNum=70).

Comment: Using a Listed product goes a long way when dealing with UL regarding enclosures. There are 3 other holes and 2 will be blanked off (to allow entry from below and either side) the unit will be supplied with 2 off H125CAP's. We want to make it as easy as possible to be installed. I know I personally hate having to go get bits when I install stuff on site.

Comment: Could you attach pictures of the items you are referencing? The links are dead at the moment.